# I have 2 lists of tuples, how can I print the difference between the second element of the tuples while leaving the first element the same?

Tags: python

Example,
I have two lists:

```
[('Joe', 10), ('Tim', 14), ('Toby', 20)]

[('Joe', 8), ('Tim', 18), ('Toby', 12)]
```

I want it to print:

```
[('Joe', 2), ('Tim', -4), ('Toby', 8)]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried: tuple(x-y for x[1],y[1] in zip(list_1, list_2)....and every variation of that....

Comment: `[(t1[0],t1[1]-t2[1]) for t1,t2 in zip(l1,l2)]` assuming that the l1 and l2 are the same order

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which features a "subtraction" version of `dict.update`.  For example:

```
>>> L1 = [('Joe', 10), ('Tim', 14), ('Toby', 20)]
>>> L2 = [('Joe', 8), ('Tim', 18), ('Toby', 12)]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c1 = Counter(dict(L1))
>>> c1.subtract(Counter(dict(L2)))
>>> print(list(c1.items()))
[('Joe', 2), ('Tim', -4), ('Toby', 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to `zip` the contents and then parse each zipped pair, doing the math and name extraction at that time.

`zip` will produce an iterable that will generate a pair of items, zippered together from each of the input items... If you were to look at these pairs, the would look something like this:

```
(('Joe', 10), ('Joe', 8))
(('Tim', 14), ('Tim', 18))
(('Toby', 20), ('Toby', 12))
```

With each item paired, it is fairly straightforward to then manipulate OR process each pair.

```
>>> l1 = [('Joe', 10), ('Tim', 14), ('Toby', 20)] 
>>> l2 = [('Joe', 8), ('Tim', 18), ('Toby', 12)]                                                                                                                                                                   
>>> new_list = []                                                                                                                                                                                                  

>>> for element1, element2 in zip(l1, l2): 
...     new_list.append((element1[0], element1[1] - element2[1])) 
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> new_list                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[('Joe', 2), ('Tim', -4), ('Toby', 8)]
```

Comment: Note this only works if both lists contain the same names in the same order. If the list sizes are different, or the names are different, or the order is different - you might get unexpected results

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to subtract the values if the names match. Try this:

```
first = [('Joe', 10), ('Tim', 14), ('Toby', 20)]
second = [('Joe', 8), ('Tim', 18), ('Toby', 12)]

access_dict = {}  # used for matching the names
for name, value in first:
    access_dict[name] = value  # add to matcher dict

for name, value in second:
    if name in access_dict:  # skip if corresponding name was not in first
        access_dict[name] = access_dict[name] - value  # subtract value

print(list(access_dict.items()))
```

Output:

```
[('Joe', 2), ('Tim', -4), ('Toby', 8)]
```

Note: this does not preserve the order of the names

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
l1=[('Joe', 10), ('Tim', 14), ('Toby', 20)]
l2=[('Joe', 8), ('Tim', 18), ('Toby', 12)]

>>> [(t1[0],t1[1]-t2[1]) for t1,t2 in zip(l1,l2)]
[('Joe', 2), ('Tim', -4), ('Toby', 8)]
```

You can add a test to make sure that the first part of the tuple is the same if appropriate:

```
[(t1[0],t1[1]-t2[1]) for t1,t2 in zip(l1,l2) if t1[0]==t2[0]]
```

But [wim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907599/298607) version using a counter is the most robust if you have lists that might have mismatched tuples.